# Updating chat messages efficiently (continuously) with Firebase's Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a React Native app that uses Firebase's Firestore for backend. Right now, every time a new message comes, I'm fetching all messages from the Firestore and updating my state, although it's just one new message that came.

```
function listenCurrentChat(dispatch, chatID) {
    const address = "chats/" + chatID + "/messages";
    firebase.firestore().collection(address).orderBy('createdAt')
        .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
            dispatch({
                type: CLEAR_MESSAGES,
                payload: {
                    chatID: chatID,
                }
            });
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                //local
                if (doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
                    dispatch({
                        type: ADD_MESSAGE,
                        payload: {
                            chatID: chatID,
                            message: {...doc.data(), createdAt: new Date()}
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    dispatch({
                        type: ADD_MESSAGE,
                        payload: {
                            chatID: chatID,
                            message: {...doc.data(), createdAt: doc.data().createdAt.toDate()}
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Obviously that's very bad, because I'm using many reads for just one new message, and also the user experience is not good at all, as there is constant lag. I also tried saving the addresses of these real time listeners in the redux state, and listening from the last message's timestamp, but that didn't seem like a good solution either, as I was not taking into consideration any more the fact that previous messages could be edited. What would be a good way to update chat conversations on the React Native part, so that I use as less Firestore reads as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it, your code is adding a one listener on a query, which will get invoked with the results of the query every time those results change.

It sounds like you are thinking that this re-reads every document every time.  That's not the way Firestore listeners work.  As long as that listener is attached, it will only read changes to that query, not the entire results of the query.  Any document from that query that doesn't change will not get re-read, even though you are observing that it gets re-delivered to the listener.  The Firebase SDK internally keeps all the documents cached in memory for as long as that listener is attached, and it will only read the minimal number of documents that are necessary to stay in sync with the server.

In other words, it is already using the minimal number of reads.

Comment: The problem is that the listener is returning all elements every time a new one is added, and it's not efficient to keep checking for any new message if it is new or if it already exists.

Comment: If you only want to know what changed since the last time your listener was invoked, you can see only those added, changed, and removed documents using `querySnapshot.docChanges()`. Processing this data doesn't incur any extra reads - all the data is already local.  See also [the documentation for this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).