# Why is my firebase chat showing messages only if I exit the screen or close the chat and re-open it?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jsx

The chat is supposed to be instant where messages populate the div as they are entered and stored in Firebase Firestore. However, I noticed a strange thing. The Chat shows a new message only when I change tabs in Chrome or when I close the chat completely and then re-open it. Otherwise, if I stay on the same tab looking at the Chat and waiting for the new message to show, it does not show up. Really strange.

JSX:

```
<div className="form-popup" id="myForm">
                    <form className="form-container" onSubmit={this.chatFormSubmit}>

                        <h1>Chat</h1>

                        <label htmlFor="msg"><b>Message</b></label>


                        <div className="chatArea" id='messages'>
                            
                            {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                             return <p key={index}>{message.body.content}</p>
                            })}

                        <div style={{ float:"left", clear: "both" }}
                               ref={(el) => { this.myRef = el; }}>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                       <textarea className="chatInput" ref={this.chatArea} ></textarea>

                        <br />
                        <br />

                        {this.state.writeError ? <p>{this.state.writeError}</p> : null}

                        <button type="submit" className="btn">Send</button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn cancel" onClick={() => this.closeForm()}>Close</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
```

REACTJS:

This is the function that opens the Chat and starts the onSnapshot function to listen to changes in Firestore:

```
startChatWithProjectManager(doc) {

            
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";

        this.setState({docId: doc.id})

        const query = firebase.firestore()
                            .collection('Clients')
                            .doc(this.state.displayName)
                            .collection('Orders')
                            .doc(doc.id)
                            .collection('Messages')
                            .where("uid", "==", this.state.uid)
                            .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                            .limit(12);              
         
            // Start listening to the query.

         this.unsubFromMessages = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === 'removed') { 
      
                console.log(change.id)

            } else {                
            
              this.setState(state => {
                const messages = [...state.messages, {id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data()}]
                return {
                    messages
                }
            }, this.scrollToBottom() ) 
            
                        
            }
            
            });
            });      
   
        
}
```

This is the function that stores new messages in Firestore:

```
chatFormSubmit(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

  this.setState({ writeError: null });

    
   firebase.firestore()
    .collection('Clients')
    .doc(this.state.displayName)
    .collection('Orders')
    .doc(this.state.docId)
    .collection('Messages')
    .doc()    
    .set({
      content: this.chatArea.current.value,
      timestamp: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'),
      uid: this.state.uid,
      name: this.state.displayName,
      email: this.state.email
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ writeError: error.message });
  })
    .then(this.chatArea.current.value = '')   
    
    }
```

For some reason, the messages appear in the ChatArea div very slowly with a weird delay unlike the examples that I followed from the Web where messages pop up almost instantly. I can not figure out what is going on.

Comment: Hi, have you checked this question ? This might be helpful on the issue you are having. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317113/updating-chat-messages-efficiently-continuously-with-firebases-firestore

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I figured it out. I had an infinite loop coming from a SetInterval function which was interfering with network requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason the chat was not updating as it was supposed to be was that one of the setInterval functions that I had was running concurrently and continuously, thus slowing down my app. Anyone out there puzzled why their code would not work when everything seems right, always check to see if there are any other functions that are causing infinite loops or other issues. Infinite loops interfere with network requests.